# Add Masonry view in Algoliya in Magento 2

Tags: algolia, masonry

I am trying to implement Masonry into my website catalog. Although I found that Masonry view is already in Algolia. I found this jsFiddle but I could not understand how do I implement this on my website. Where to add this java Script code. 
if any one knows this, would be appreciated.

`[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/vw53u259`  js fiddle code

Comment: Could you tell us more about your website? Are you using an e-commerce platform?

Comment: Yes, i am using Magento 2.3